# Map a value in multi dimensional tensor to another value

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, mapping, tensor

I have a 4 dimensional tensor of ints, I want to map one of the values to another. I am not sure what would be an efficient way to do this in tensorflow.

If it was a numpy array, I would do as follows:

`arrayNew = np.zeros(arrayOld.shape, dtype=arrayOld.dtype)
arrayNew[arrayOld == valOld] = valNew`

So I'm basically looking to translate this code to tensorflow.

Comment: Are `valOld` and `valNew` scalars?

Comment: yes, they are uint8 in my example.

Comment: I see, I changed my answer accordingly. Does it solve the problem for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you just want to replace one scalar value with another, maybe the easiest way is to subtract the old value and add the new one:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# Inputs
arrayOld = tf.placeholder(tf.int8)
valOld = tf.placeholder(tf.int8, ())
valNew = tf.placeholder(tf.int8, ())
# Find positions to replace
mask = tf.cast(tf.equal(arrayOld, valOld), arrayOld.dtype)
# Make new array
arrayNew = arrayOld + (valNew - valOld) * mask
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(arrayNew, feed_dict={
        arrayOld: [[12, 20, 32, 17, 20],
                   [31, 15, 20, 25, 14]],
        valOld: 20, valNew: 10}))
```

Output:

```
[[12 10 32 17 10]
 [31 15 10 25 14]]
```

EDIT: Initially, I thought the line

```
arrayNew = arrayOld + (valNew - valOld) * mask
```

could be problematic for unsigned types (because of the subtraction producing negative values), but it actually works fine, negative values just overflow and the result ends up correct.